# Hibernate - How to disable mapping for a column

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

When tagged as @Entity, each attribute of a class is mapped to one database column.
I have some classes where I want to add some fields for internal usage, but I don't want them to be mapped by hibernate to a database column.
Is there a way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its either you mark the variables with @javax.persistence.Transient or declare it as transient.

```
@javax.persistence.Transient
String myTransietnColumn;



transient String myAnotherTransientColumn;
```